# Save with UserDefaults that checkbox is check or uncheck swift

Tags: swift, checkbox

I solved the problem

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let save = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "RememberMe")
            self.circleBox.isChecked = save
}
@objc func checkboxvalue(sender: Checkbox) {
        if sender.isChecked == true {
            labelcheckbox.text = ("Beni")
            action((Any).self)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"RememberMe");


        }else{
            labelcheckbox.text = ("")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey:"RememberMe");

        }

    }
```

I've designed a recall checkbox. But when I log out of the application, I want the checkbox value to be set to UserDefaults as true or false. So I want the checkbox to remember true or false when I get into the application.

```
 lazy var circleBox: Checkbox = {

        let squareBox = Checkbox(frame: CGRect(x: 22, y: 290, width: 25, height: 25))
        squareBox.tintColor = .black
        squareBox.borderStyle = .square
        squareBox.checkmarkStyle = .square
        squareBox.uncheckedBorderColor = .lightGray
        squareBox.borderWidth = 1

        squareBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxvalue(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return squareBox

    }()

 @objc func checkboxvalue(sender: Checkbox) {
        if sender.isChecked == true {
            labelcheckbox.text = ("Remember me")
            action((Any).self)


        }else{
            labelcheckbox.text = ("Don't remember")

        }

    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem? I didn't understand. You can save the value to user defaults. When the view loads either check or uncheck it based on the data in the user defaults.

Comment: use userdefault to save value of checkbox, always use userdefault value to enable or disable checkbox

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isChecked")  //true and false acc to action